# Adding all items in Available-Item Section to Devexpress Layout Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, devexpress

I try using [Devexpress Layout-Control](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8147) (For costume usage). So I want add all item's exist in `Available-Item Section` to Layout-Control root as `Layout-Item` via code .

So it must be possible, **`But How?`** (I don't know, any solution ;)

**Edit 1**  sorry For less information at first time

Let me explain What I do in My example, I Use code to create one or more Control in Layout-Control at `Form-Loaded Event`.

After that in one `Button_Click`, I Use :

```
 Layout1.WriteToXML(XmlWriter_Object);
```

to save **`Layout Current View`**. These step work well! if I want recover that view at next step with this command :

```
 Layout1.ReadFromXML(XmlReader_Object);
```

As Result I got all item's(which created via code) in Available-Item Section! So this is My problem!

Why These Happend?

> Ps: Both XmlReader_Object and XmlWriter_Object refer same file on machin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To move an item from the [Available Items](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument9253) list onto the LayoutControl, do the following.

1) Remove the item from the LayoutControl.AvailableItems collection:

```
layoutControl1.AvailableItems.Remove(item1);
```

2) Add this item to the layout. For instance, you can use the following code to append the item to a group:

```
layoutGroup1.Children.Add(item1);
```

**Update on Edit1:**

When creating layout items dynamically(in code), it is necessary to register their identifiera(names) using the [RegisterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) method.  The code can look as follows:

```
LayoutItem layoutItem1 = new LayoutItem()
{
    Name = "Item1",
    Label = "Item1",
    Content = new Button()
    {
        Content = "Button"
    }
};
RegisterName(layoutItem1.Name, layoutItem1);
layoutGroup1.Children.Add(layoutItem1);
```

This way, everything should work as expected.

Comment: @DimitryG Thanks, It worked. But Why? can you describe different!

Comment: Items within the layout are restored by their names. It required the FrameworkElement.FindName() method call, but this method returns only items with registered names. When you created your layout via XAML-markup the RegisterName() method invoked automatically (on x:Name="..."), but when the layout created in code-behind you should call this method yourself.

Comment: DimitryG sorry but I have same problem in Silverlight!bad news silverlight don't have RegisterName method! How do this?